# Python Request with Cookies - Content blocked by Cookie Banner

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, cookies, python-requests

I'm trying to access a website via Python Requests. To avoid the iframe of the "Cookie Banner" I want to pass the cookie that handles the banner.

With Selenium I already managed to figure out which cookie that is and there it works fine with just passing the key/value" pair. I already found online, that it is necessary to "get" the page before passing and then refreshing it with "get" again after adding the cookies.

```python
website = "https://www.myfitnesspal.com"
path =  "path/to/your/chromedriver.exe"
service = Service(executable_path=path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service = service)

driver.get(website)
driver.add_cookie({'name': 'notice_preferences','value': '2:'})
driver.get(website)
```

So far so good. However, if I pass the same cookie that already worked in Selenium to a Python Request, the response.text that I receive still shows the content of the iframe and "Cookie Banner".

```python
response = requests.get(website, cookies={"notice_preferences":"2:"})
```

Does anyone know why this is happening or if there is even a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that page's content is blocked by cookie banner. It's rather blocked by the lack of a proper user-agent in header. The following code will return the page content as seen in browser:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


s = requests.Session()

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com'

s.headers.update(headers)
s.cookies.set("name", "notice_preferences", domain="www.myfitnesspal.com/")
s.cookies.set("value", "2:", domain="www.myfitnesspal.com/")
r = s.get(url)
# print(r.text)
print(s.cookies)
```

Result printed in terminal:

```
<RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie split-id=e28e4968-c2e3-4145-9226-0d9db15bcffe for www.myfitnesspal.com/>, <Cookie name=notice_preferences for www.myfitnesspal.com//>, <Cookie value=2: for www.myfitnesspal.com//>]>
```

You can then navigate to another page in that website, and requests' Session will preserve the headers and cookies. Also, print out the text response, see if the info you're looking for is there.
For more info on Requests, you can visit https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

EDIT: This is an `a la carte` XY problem - luckily the OP clarified it in comments.
That data is being pulled via an XHR call from an API endpoint. To get the info youi want, you need to scrape the endpoint. THis is how you do it (after inspecting Dev Tools - Network Tab and seeing that endpoint):

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


s = requests.Session()

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

url = 'https://www.myfitnesspal.com/api/nutrition?query=banane&page=1&offset=10'

r = s.get(url)

df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['items'])
display(df)
```

This will print in terminal:

```
item    tags    type
0   {'country_code': 'US', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane', 'id': 1873022840, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0.5, 'carbohydrates': 22.84, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 89}, 'fat': 0.33, 'fiber': 2.6, 'iron': 1.44444, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0.032, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0.073, 'potassium': 358, 'protein': 1.09, 'saturated_fat': 0.112, 'sodium': 1, 'sugar': 12.23, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 4.26667, 'vitamin_c': 14.5, 'vitamin_d': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '67628178485117', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1.18, 'unit': 'medium', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67078422671357', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1.36, 'unit': 'large', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67628178485245', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1.5, 'unit': 'cup, sliced', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67078414315389', 'index': 3, 'nutrition_multiplier': 2.25, 'unit': 'cup, mashed', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67628170129277', 'index': 4, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67078414315517', 'index': 5, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'oz', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67628170129405', 'index': 6, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.81, 'unit': 'extra small', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67078422703997', 'index': 7, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1.52, 'unit': 'extra large', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67628178517885', 'index': 8, 'nutrition_multiplier': 4.53592, 'unit': 'lb(s)', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67078422704125', 'index': 9, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1e-05, 'unit': 'mg(s)', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67628178518013', 'index': 10, 'nutrition_multiplier': 10, 'unit': 'kg(s)', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67076304547197', 'index': 11, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.00625, 'unit': 'mL, sliced ', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67626060361085', 'index': 12, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.009375, 'unit': 'mL, mashed ', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67076304547325', 'index': 13, 'nutrition_multiplier': 6.25, 'unit': 'liter(s), sliced ', 'value': 1}, {'id': '67626060361213', 'index': 14, 'nutrition_multiplier': 9.375, 'unit': 'liter(s), mashed ', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '133476501057389', 'verified': True, 'version': '199432263862133'}   [canonical, best_match] food
1   {'brand_name': 'Banane', 'country_code': 'FR', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Une banane', 'id': 2007191148, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0, 'carbohydrates': 27, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 105}, 'fat': 0.4, 'fiber': 2.1, 'iron': 0, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0, 'potassium': 0, 'protein': 1.3, 'saturated_fat': 0, 'sodium': 0, 'sugar': 12, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 0, 'vitamin_c': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '93902759513197', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'fruit entier (120g)', 'value': 1}, {'id': '94452515327085', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.00833333, 'unit': 'gram', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '160406080319149', 'verified': False, 'version': '198055450101605'} []  food
2   {'brand_name': 'Obst', 'country_code': 'DE', 'deleted': False, 'description': ' Banane ()', 'id': 1659839707, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0.625, 'carbohydrates': 22.84, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 90}, 'fat': 0.33, 'fiber': 2.6, 'iron': 1.857, 'potassium': 358, 'protein': 1.09, 'sodium': 1, 'sugar': 12.23, 'vitamin_a': 0.375, 'vitamin_c': 10.875}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '268297681372533', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 100}, {'id': '268297681372661', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '268847437186549', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}, {'id': '268297673016693', 'index': 3, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.992232, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 3.5}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '163850601983789', 'verified': False, 'version': '129355447387317'}    []  food
3   {'brand_name': 'Obst', 'country_code': 'DE', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane 1 Stück', 'id': 1887842011, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0, 'carbohydrates': 26.4, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 115}, 'fat': 0.2, 'iron': 0, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0, 'potassium': 0, 'protein': 1.2, 'saturated_fat': 0, 'sodium': 0, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 0, 'vitamin_c': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '27521653231597', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 120}, {'id': '28071409045485', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.00833333, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '27521661620077', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.236246, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '234889390534445', 'verified': False, 'version': '53489009870261'}   []  food
4   {'brand_name': 'Obst', 'country_code': 'DE', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane', 'id': 227750309, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 5, 'carbohydrates': 22.8, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 89}, 'fat': 0.3, 'fiber': 2.6, 'iron': 0.3, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0.1, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0.1, 'potassium': 358, 'protein': 1.1, 'saturated_fat': 0.1, 'sodium': 1, 'sugar': 12, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 64, 'vitamin_c': 9}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '88267487686061', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 100}, {'id': '88817243499949', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '88267496074541', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '134026256871405', 'verified': True, 'version': '230354056064301'} []  food
5   {'brand_name': 'Banane Ohne Schale', 'country_code': 'DE', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane', 'id': 1889101676, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0.625, 'carbohydrates': 22.84, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 95}, 'fat': 0.33, 'fiber': 2.6, 'iron': 35.71, 'potassium': 358, 'protein': 1.09, 'sugar': 12.23, 'vitamin_a': 0.375, 'vitamin_c': 10.875}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '138151424970349', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 100}, {'id': '137601669156589', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '138151424970477', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '278614430748141', 'verified': False, 'version': '53074667210277'}    []  food
6   {'brand_name': 'Banane', 'country_code': 'FR', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane Gebacken', 'id': 1349524295, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0, 'carbohydrates': 25, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 157}, 'fat': 4, 'fiber': 0, 'iron': 0, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0, 'potassium': 0, 'protein': 4, 'saturated_fat': 0, 'sodium': 1, 'sugar': 12, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 0, 'vitamin_c': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '59106944525429', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 100}, {'id': '58557188711669', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '59106944525557', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}, {'id': '58557197100149', 'index': 3, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.992232, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 3.5}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '133324127170493', 'verified': False, 'version': '31634077001709'}    []  food
7   {'brand_name': 'Banane', 'country_code': 'FR', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Demi banane', 'id': 139561661, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 0, 'carbohydrates': 14, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 93}, 'fat': 2, 'fiber': 0, 'iron': 0, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0, 'potassium': 0, 'protein': 3, 'saturated_fat': 0, 'sodium': 0, 'sugar': 0, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 0, 'vitamin_c': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '124397058706493', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'yaourt', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '133476501057517', 'verified': False, 'version': '63530949537133'}    []  food
8   {'brand_name': 'Banane', 'country_code': 'CA', 'deleted': False, 'description': 'Banane (Santé Canada)', 'id': 1568891032, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 1, 'carbohydrates': 27, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 105}, 'fat': 0, 'fiber': 3, 'iron': 2, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0, 'potassium': 487, 'protein': 1, 'saturated_fat': 0, 'sodium': 1, 'sugar': 14, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 2, 'vitamin_c': 17}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '27092291822629', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'banana 118g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '26542536008869', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'med bananna', 'value': 1}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '199722294733869', 'verified': False, 'version': '264028726224173'}   []  food
9   {'brand_name': 'Banane', 'country_code': 'CA', 'deleted': False, 'description': ' Une banane moyenne', 'id': 1484522768, 'nutritional_contents': {'calcium': 1.53, 'carbohydrates': 22.8, 'cholesterol': 0, 'energy': {'unit': 'calories', 'value': 89}, 'fat': 0.33, 'fiber': 2, 'iron': 0, 'monounsaturated_fat': 0, 'polyunsaturated_fat': 0.07, 'potassium': 0, 'protein': 1.1, 'saturated_fat': 0.11, 'sodium': 8, 'sugar': 12, 'trans_fat': 0, 'vitamin_a': 0, 'vitamin_c': 0}, 'public': True, 'serving_sizes': [{'id': '63099251926181', 'index': 0, 'nutrition_multiplier': 1, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 100}, {'id': '63649007740069', 'index': 1, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.01, 'unit': 'g', 'value': 1}, {'id': '63099260314661', 'index': 2, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.283495, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 1}, {'id': '63649016128549', 'index': 3, 'nutrition_multiplier': 0.992232, 'unit': 'ounce', 'value': 3.5}], 'type': 'food', 'user_id': '128659968929645', 'verified': False, 'version': '136640012748413'}    []  food
```

You can drill down further into that json object, (normalize it, etc) to get data in different shapes and forms.

Comment: Hmm, that seems not to work for me. I can show you a screenshot where I test that. And if I search for the content of the Cookie Banner within the response.text I can still find the "Accept"-Button. Also the fields that I want to extract are not accessible.

Comment: Are you sure the info you want to extract is not generated by javascript, hence request cannot see/access it? @DJM

Comment: So if I do the same task with Selenium, I'm using driver.page_source, which also returns the html code of the side. The page source is the same as in the request (the content banner) until I add cookies or click on the "Accept" Button and change the iframe via automation. After that I can access the information I want via driver.page_source. However, Selenium is super slow I want to speed up the process (beside multi threading).

Comment: @DJM I updated my answer with a way to set cookies in requests Session. Check now if the info you're looking for is there.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately not. I tried all the different forms...cookies as dict, cookies as cookiejars and session cookies. To be more precise with the url, I'm using this one: "https://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/search?page=1&query=banane". The result should return nutrition information. I parse the result with BeautifulSoup and search for hrefs with: parsed_html.find_all("div", {"class": "MuiBox-root css-1cheb17"}). If the content of the html is displayed correctly, this will return different sublinks from this domain. If the content banner is activate, it does not find any link.

Comment: @DJM: Your issue is (hopefully) solved - check the updated answer. Next time please clarify your end goals in the actual question.

Comment: Ahh, thank you so much! You are my savior... I read online about XHR Requests but when I opened Dev Tools - Network Tab and filter on Fetch/XHR I did not know what to do from there. What am I looking for?

Comment: I checked again and found it. Thanks a lot! Also accepted your answer. Have a nice day.

Comment: Hi again, sorry to ask another question to the same topic... I tried to find a similar solution for "https://www.calorie-charts.info/food/all/banana". However, the request loads forever without finishing. Furthermore I looked for an XHR Request but I couldnt find a proper one in the Network Tab of Chrome Dev Tools. Do you have an idea?

Comment: Hello @DJM, I do have a solution, please ask another question and I will sort it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73716895/python-request-takes-forever-cant-find-proper-xhr-request

Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome @DJM - I posted a solution, please accept it if it solved your issue.